# How to use a repeater with jquery 'VTicker' slidebar plugin?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm using the "[VTicker](http://www.jugbit.com/jquery-vticker-vertical-news-ticker/)" jquery plugin for showing top news of my web site.

At first I was using static html code for testing this plugin and every thing was ok!

But I need to read data from database and then bind data to asp.net repeater and then show repeater data by vticker plugin.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the VTicker manual, says that the html structure looks like:

```
<div class='myclass'>
   <ul>
      <li>some content</li>
      <li>some content</li>
      ...
   </ul>
</div>
```

So this can be made using a repeater as:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpTicker" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div class="myclass"><ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><%#Eval("TicketText")%></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul></div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The rest on how you call the jQuery call is not change.

reference:
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/vTicker

about the repeater, you can find many examples on internet on how to set your data on it. Some examples

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=663

Comment: I would add placing the "header" and "footer" tags in the header/footer templates of repeater. this way you don't have an empty div/ul tag if there is no data.

Comment: @JasonMeckley nice idea !, if you wish you can edit my answer and place them.

Comment: thank you , but it didn't work again,i moved <ul> element before <asp:repeater> and it worked correctly